# Play local sound on watchOS button tap

Tags: swift, avfoundation, watchkit, avaudioplayer, watchos

I'm new to swift development and building a simple app for the apple watch. I'd like a short sound to play when a button is tapped. Is this possible?

From what I understand the best way to do this is with AVFoundation and AVAudioPlayer. There seem to have been a lot of updates for this in the last few releases and I'm finding conflicting advice. Based on a few tutorials I've put this simple test together, but I'm getting a **"Thread 1:Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil when unwrapping an Optional value"** Here is my code:

```
import WatchKit
import Foundation
import AVFoundation

var dogSound = AVAudioPlayer()


class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {

    override func awake(withContext context: Any?) {
        super.awake(withContext: context)

        // Configure interface objects here.
    }

    override func willActivate() {
        // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
        super.willActivate()
    }

    override func didDeactivate() {
        // This method is called when watch view controller is no longer visible
        super.didDeactivate()
    }

    @IBAction func playTapped() {

        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Dog", ofType: ".mp3")!
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)

        do {
            dogSound = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
            dogSound.play()
        } catch {
            //couldn't load file :(
        }

    }
}
```

My audio file is an **mp3** named **Dog** in the **Assets.xcassets** folder in **WatchKit Extension** and I have added **AVFoundation.framework** to the **Link Binary with Libraries**

What am I doing wrong and is there a tutorial for the right way to implement this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: were you able to resolve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Use AVSession instead:

```
import Foundation
import AVFAudio

final class AudioManager {
     var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?
    static let shared = AudioManager()
}


extension AudioManager: AudioManagerProtocol {

func start() {
    play("start")
}

fileprivate func play(_ filename: String) {
    guard let soundURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: filename, withExtension: "mp3") else { return }
    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
        audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: soundURL)
        audioPlayer?.play()
    } catch {
        print("Error al inicializar el reproductor de audio: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
}
```

In my case I indluded a file called 'start.mp3':

[image]